# How to Get Qibla Direction at Compass Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, compass

I'm developing an Islamic app which has Qibla feature. 
I can determine Qibla direction in degrees from my current location using my longitude and latitude. 
For examle: From Cairo, Qibla direction will be 137 degree.
How to make compass sensor in windows phone navigate to this angle?

Edit:

I'm using this method to get sensor heading readings:

```
public void RunCompass()
{
    try
    {
        if (Compass.IsSupported)
        {
            // If compass sensor is supported create new compass object and attach event handlers
            Compass myCompass = new Compass();
            // This defines how often heading is updated
            myCompass.TimeBetweenUpdates = System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100); 
            myCompass.Calibrate += new System.EventHandler<CalibrationEventArgs>((s, e) =>
            {
                // This will show the calibration screen
                this.IsCalibrationNeeded = true;
            });
            myCompass.CurrentValueChanged += new System.EventHandler<SensorReadingEventArgs<CompassReading>>((s, e) =>
            {
                // This will update the current heading value. We have to put it in correct direction
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    CurrentHeading =   e.SensorReading.TrueHeading;
                    if (CurrentHeading >= (RotationAngel - 10) && CurrentHeading <= (RotationAngel + 10))
                    {
                        //Show Kaba
                        KabaVisability = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        KabaVisability = false;
                    }                       
                });
            });
            // Start receiving data from compass sensor
            myCompass.Start();              
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm use CurrentHeading as rotation angel of my pointer.
RotaionAgel is angle for Qibla for example 137.

My XAML Code:

```
<Grid> 
 <Ellipse>
  <Ellipse.Fill>
   <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/qebla_new.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
  </Ellipse.Fill>
  </Ellipse>
  <Border x:Name="head" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="191,0" Padding="0,66,0,162" UseLayoutRounding="False">
   <Border.RenderTransform>
      <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding CurrentHeading,Mode=TwoWay}">     
   </RotateTransform> <!---->
   </Border.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unclear what you are asking us to do. Write the code for you? Help you find documentation? Have you tried? What current code is causing problem for you?

Comment: Really!! Off course no, I'm not the type of people ask about full code. I'm already wrote it and calculate the direction and after a week of search I can't find the way represent my angle to the compass to get qibla direction. Note: I don't ask at stackoverflow unless I can't found what I'm looking for after search. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Close vote retracted after edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a similar thing one app, showing a compass pointing to a selected landmark (Mecca in your case). I used this code to calculate the bearing:

```
public static class DistanceCalculator
{
    const double kDegreesToRadians = Math.PI / 180.0;
    const double kRadiansToDegrees = 180.0 / Math.PI;


    public static double Bearing(GeoCoordinate position, GeoCoordinate location)
    {
        double fromLong = position.Longitude * kDegreesToRadians;
        double toLong = location.Longitude * kDegreesToRadians;
        double fromLat = position.Latitude * kDegreesToRadians;

        double dlon = toLong - fromLong;
        double y = Math.Sin(dlon) * Math.Cos(toLat);
        double x = Math.Cos(fromLat) * Math.Sin(toLat) - Math.Sin(fromLat) * Math.Cos(toLat) * Math.Cos(dlon);

        double direction = Math.Atan2(y, x);

        // convert to degrees
        direction = direction * kRadiansToDegrees;
        // normalize
        double fraction = modf(direction + 360.0, direction);
        direction += fraction;

        if (direction > 360)
        {
            direction -= 360;
        }

        return direction;
    }

    private static double modf(double orig, double ipart)
    {
        return orig - (Math.Floor(orig));
    }
}
```

and used it with

```
var res = DistanceCalculator.Bearing(Position, SelectedPlace.Position);
TargetHeading = (360 - res) % 360;
```

I then get my current real heading from the compass

```
CurrentHeading = 360 - e.SensorReading.TrueHeading;
```

and use the difference

```
 public double HeadingDifference
 {
    get
    {
        return CurrentHeading - TargetHeading;
    }
 }
```

to point the arrow in XAML

```
<Image Source="/Assets/sn_ico_et_compass_whitepointer.png" x:Name="arrow">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding HeadingDifference}" CenterX="240" CenterY="240" x:Name="arrowTransform" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Comment: I already calculated the direction in degrees with another method it gives me the same result your method gives. If the direction your method return is 137. you mean you set the target heading with (360 - 137) % 360 which will be 223. If I make it as a rotation angle to my heading. So where I use compass reading (SensorReading). I need formula to be used when the sensor reading changes I can make the heading changes to the right direction of my distance. Hope you can get it.

Comment: sorry, I do not really remember how the code works .. I updated my answer and added the missing things

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Help :)