# Make Compass to always point to a specific place in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement Compass following [Xamarin.Essentials: Compass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/compass?tabs=android) to head to a specific point. For the sake of implementation and testing, I added SfCircularGauge which works well with the same logic. Since, I don't want to use XF, so tried it without XF. But when working without XF, the arrow doesn't point to the correct direction and the arrow points to North only. The calculation and points are identical, it is all about the arrow doesn't point to the correct direction. (I am testing in iOS, didn't checked it in Android)

```
double current_latitude = 25.2618616; // changed on Appearing
double current_longitude = 55.3254198; // changed on Appearing
readonly double QiblaLatitude = 21.4224779; //remains --> pointing to this location
readonly double QiblaLongitude = 39.8251832; //remains --> pointing to this location
readonly SensorSpeed speed = SensorSpeed.UI;
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Compass.ReadingChanged += Compass_ReadingChanged;
  if (!Compass.IsMonitoring) Compass.Start(speed);
}
void Compass_ReadingChanged(object sender, CompassChangedEventArgs e)
{
    circularGauge.RotateTo(360 - e.Reading.HeadingMagneticNorth); // this is XF
    compassImage.RotateTo(360 - e.Reading.HeadingMagneticNorth);
    ImageArrow.RotateTo(360 - e.Reading.HeadingMagneticNorth);
    PointToQibla();
}
private async void GetLocation()
{
   try
   {
      var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
      var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);
      current_latitude = location.Latitude;
      current_longitude = location.Longitude;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);}
}
private double Mod(double a, double b)
{
   return a - b * Math.Floor(a / b);
}
void PointToQibla()
{
   double latt_from_radians = current_latitude * Math.PI / 180;
   double long_from_radians = current_longitude * Math.PI / 180;
   double latt_to_radians = QiblaLatitude * Math.PI / 180;
   double lang_to_radians = QiblaLongitude * Math.PI / 180;
   double bearing = Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(lang_to_radians - long_from_radians) * Math.Cos(latt_to_radians), (Math.Cos(latt_from_radians) * Math.Sin(latt_to_radians)) - (Math.Sin(latt_from_radians) * Math.Cos(latt_to_radians) * Math.Cos(lang_to_radians - long_from_radians)));
   bearing = Mod(bearing, 2 * Math.PI);
   double bearing_degree = bearing * 180 / Math.PI;
   //normal arrow and XF
   ImageArrow.Rotation = pointer1.Value = bearing_degree;
   // Labels to show value 
   lblG.Text = LabelInfo.Text = string.Format("Lat: {0} Long: {1} degree:{2}", current_latitude,current_longitude,bearing_degree.ToString());
}
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    GetLocation();
}
```

XAML (both XF and normal)

```
<Grid Padding="20" BackgroundColor="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
            <SyncfusionGauge:SfCircularGauge
                                         x:Name="circularGauge"
                                         BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <SyncfusionGauge:SfCircularGauge.Scales>
                    <SyncfusionGauge:Scale x:Name="scale"
                                       StartAngle="270"
                                       StartValue="0"
                                       EndValue="360"
                                       Interval="45"
                                       LabelOffset="0.75"
                                       SweepAngle="360"
                                       MinorTicksPerInterval="1"
                                       ShowLastLabel="False"
                                       ScaleStartOffset="0.99"
                                       ScaleEndOffset="0.9"
                                       LabelCreated="Scale_LabelCreated">
                        <SyncfusionGauge:Scale.Pointers>
                            <SyncfusionGauge:NeedlePointer x:Name="pointer1"
                                                       Type="Triangle"
                                                       LengthFactor="0.65"
                                                       KnobColor="White"
                                                       Thickness="25"
                                                       EnableAnimation="True">
                                <SyncfusionGauge:NeedlePointer.KnobRadius>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <On Platform="UWP"
                                        Value="15" />
                                        <On Platform="Android"
                                        Value="25" />
                                        <On Platform="iOS"
                                        Value="25" />
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </SyncfusionGauge:NeedlePointer.KnobRadius>
                            </SyncfusionGauge:NeedlePointer>
                        </SyncfusionGauge:Scale.Pointers>
                        <SyncfusionGauge:Scale.MajorTickSettings>
                            <SyncfusionGauge:TickSettings StartOffset="0.9"
                                                      EndOffset="0.83"
                                                      Thickness="2" />
                        </SyncfusionGauge:Scale.MajorTickSettings>
                        <SyncfusionGauge:Scale.MinorTickSettings>
                            <SyncfusionGauge:TickSettings StartOffset="0.9"
                                                      EndOffset="0.85"
                                                      Thickness="2" />
                        </SyncfusionGauge:Scale.MinorTickSettings>
                    </SyncfusionGauge:Scale>
                </SyncfusionGauge:SfCircularGauge.Scales>
            </SyncfusionGauge:SfCircularGauge>
            <Label x:Name="lblG" TextColor="Red"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="compassImage" Source="compass.png"/>
                <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="arrow.png" x:Name="ImageArrow"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="1" x:Name="LabelInfo" TextColor="Blue"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

The issue is the arrow doesn't point to the specific direction, but it remains in north always.
The project is also available in [GitHub](https://github.com/arahmancsd/QiblaFinder)

[image: iOS Screenshot]

Comment: are you updating `ImageArrow.Rotation` on the UI thread?  If you hardcode the Rotation value does it display correctly?  Are you sure all of your math is correct?

Comment: It changes with this code as well, but it doesn't stay at that point.

Comment: Settings static values doesn't change. With the above code, it points to the correct direction, but it doesn't stay there.

Comment: you are updating `ImageArrow's` rotation property twice - once by calling RotateTo() and once by setting it directly.  Is there reason for this?

Comment: Removing that line points to the correct direction and stays there, but doesn’t change when you change the mobile directions as the xf changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this mystery following [How to Get Qibla Direction at Compass Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439622/how-to-get-qibla-direction-at-compass-windows-phone-8)
. The updated code likes like below;

```
void Compass_ReadingChanged(object sender, CompassChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Qibla lat and long
                var qiblaLocation = new Location(QiblaLatitude, QiblaLongitude);
                //current position
                var position = new Location(current_latitude, current_longitude);
                var res = DistanceCalculator.Bearing(position, qiblaLocation);
                var TargetHeading = (360 - res) % 360;

                var currentHeading = 360 - e.Reading.HeadingMagneticNorth;
                Heading = currentHeading - TargetHeading;
                
                Info = string.Format("Lat: {0} Long: {1} degree:{2}", current_latitude, current_longitude, Heading);

            }catch(Exception ex){//log exception}
        }
```

The complete project is in [GitHub](https://github.com/arahmancsd/QiblaFinder)